# Что значит ошибка: "Значение было недопустимо малым или недопустимо большим для Int32"?

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

Имеем программу:

```
var a, b: real;

function dg0(a, b : real) : real;
var
  dg : real;
  f, r : longint;
begin
  r := 1;
  repeat 
    a := a * b;
    f := trunc(a);
    dg := dg + f * r;
  until a - trunc(a) = 0;
  writeln(dg);
  dg0 := dg;
end;
begin
  readln(a, b);
  writeln(dg0(a, b));
  writeln('Нажмите Enter для выхода из программы');
  readln;
end.
```

Она должна переводить дробную часть десятичного числа `а` в систему счисления с основанием `b` (ввод числа в формате 0.111). На 12 строчке (`f := trunc(a);`) выдает ошибку:

> Pattern.pas(12) : Ошибка времени выполнения: Значение было недопустимо малым или недопустимо большим для Int32.

Прошу объяснить, в чем ошибка

Comment: @nikrom3000 отформатируйте пожалуйста код по-человечески. Для этого есть специальная кнопка **{}** в редакторе вопроса

Answer (score 1):

Вам же написали: *Значение было недопустимо малым или недопустимо большим для Int32.*

У вас `f` типа `longint` это то же, что и `Int32`. Скорее всего, целая часть `a` больше, чем может поместиться в `Int32` (-2147483648..2147483647 или -2^31..2^31-1). Строчкой выше вы умножаете `a` на `b`.